# Sonar server is not coming up

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed Sonar on a windows machine and when I am trying to run it am getting the below error and the sonar is not coming up.

Could someone help on this.

Sonar start up log (below) -

```
*Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:30:05 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:30:26 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+
UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp -javaagent:D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp\
sq-process5784289335367032457properties
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:32:29 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:32:29 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp -javaagent:D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\lib\jdbc\postgresql\postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.ser
ver.app.WebServer D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp\sq-process7712868170609596655properties
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:34:52 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:34:52 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Agile\NewSonarQub
e\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp -javaagent:D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\lib\jdbc\postgresql\postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp\sq-
process6453747015728432890properties
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:35:21 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:35:21 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:35:30 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:35:30 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2019.06.24 16:35:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped*
```

Also attaching the 'sonar.log' here below -

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2019.07.03 11:24:28 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp
2019.07.03 11:24:30 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp -javaagent:D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp\sq-process7809422627146396746properties
2019.07.03 11:24:30 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2019.07.03 11:24:30 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2019.07.03 11:24:31 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] version[1.7.5], pid[8484], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2019.07.03 11:24:31 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] initializing ...
2019.07.03 11:24:31 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1562133268619] loaded [], sites []
2019.07.03 11:24:31 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1562133268619] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(D:)]], net usable_space [79.6gb], net total_space [131.9gb], types [NTFS]
2019.07.03 11:24:32 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2019.07.03 11:24:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] initialized
2019.07.03 11:24:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] starting ...
2019.07.03 11:24:33 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1562133268619] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2019.07.03 11:24:33 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1562133268619] sonarqube/XGZJsELLSXuNlBZ4G449tw
2019.07.03 11:24:36 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1562133268619] new_master [sonar-1562133268619][XGZJsELLSXuNlBZ4G449tw][CLBBLR-5070][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1562133268619}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2019.07.03 11:24:36 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] started
2019.07.03 11:24:36 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1562133268619] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
2019.07.03 11:24:39 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2019.07.03 11:24:39 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp -javaagent:D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\lib\jdbc\postgresql\postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp\sq-process6230173931576405711properties
2019.07.03 11:24:40 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2019.07.03 11:24:41 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\web
2019.07.03 11:24:41 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2019.07.03 11:24:41 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2019.07.03 11:24:42 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6.6 / e8e13145497bb920921ae4fe11b09f0903f1d298
2019.07.03 11:24:42 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
2019.07.03 11:24:43 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6
2019.07.03 11:24:43 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1562133268619] loaded [], sites []
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Android / 1.1 / 9ab2bbcc83177e67c74d365f009bfe05bf38c7e3
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 6.3.0.2862 / 1600df4ea68defd03b270da8e2935cfbf342cd8e
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin CSS / SCSS / Less / 3.1 / 58a0a86a53f82a8486a5ee93681257e1ae0a10c8
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 3.7 / 
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Cobertura / 1.7 / d14b7978322d19a2795286ebfed225a57b13c3af
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin CodeCracker for C# / 1.0.1
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin ESLint / 0.1.1
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin PL/SQL (Community) / 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT / 
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin PMD / 2.6 / f419f834b4bea51f9b6da33517b7f6186db5c066
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJS / 3.1.1.5128 / 564d130c281685fde03e85964417158e32a17b2b
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJava / 4.12.0.11033 / fa9fe66b0cb1b6ab8d7f341cc1f7908897a9cf33
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPHP / 2.11.0.2485 / 741861a29e5f9a26c6c99c06268facb6c4f4a882
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarXML / 1.4.3.1027 / 39588245cecf538bb27be4e496ff303b0143d20b
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Sonargraph / 3.5
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Timeline / 1.5 / a9cae1328fd455a128b5d7d603381f47398c6e2a
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin TypeScript / 1.2.0-rc1
2019.07.03 11:24:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Web / 2.5.0.476 / 636872f5d37fa7a440fe07d08d504e1a881225e5
2019.07.03 11:24:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2019.07.03 11:24:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2019.07.03 11:24:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2019.07.03 11:24:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2019.07.03 11:24:50 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2019.07.03 11:24:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2019.07.03 11:24:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
2019.07.03 11:24:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2019.07.03 11:24:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2019.07.03 11:24:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2019.07.03 11:24:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index activities
2019.07.03 11:24:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
2019.07.03 11:24:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
2019.07.03 11:24:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
2019.07.03 11:24:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
2019.07.03 11:24:57 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_65-b17 [Windows 7-amd64]
2019.07.03 11:24:57 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@649f4774 [pattern=/sessions/init/*]
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@18a75007 [pattern=/oauth2/callback/*]
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2019.07.03 11:25:09 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp -javaagent:D:\Agile\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\lib\jdbc\postgresql\postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6\temp\sq-process9172021716354276652properties
2019.07.03 11:25:10 INFO  ce[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2019.07.03 11:25:10 INFO  ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting up...
2019.07.03 11:25:10 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6.6 / e8e13145497bb920921ae4fe11b09f0903f1d298
2019.07.03 11:25:10 INFO  ce[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
2019.07.03 11:25:11 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: D:\Agile\NewSonarQube\sonarqube-5.6.6
2019.07.03 11:25:11 INFO  ce[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1562133268619] loaded [], sites []
2019.07.03 11:25:12 INFO  ce[o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2019.07.03 11:25:17 ERROR ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine startup failed
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ce_activity_uuid"
  Detail: Key (uuid)=(AWpKhMdKhBAmaVnZ4vza) already exists.
### The error may involve org.sonar.db.ce.CeActivityMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into ce_activity     (uuid, component_uuid, snapshot_id, status, task_type, is_last, is_last_key, submitter_login, submitted_at, started_at,     executed_at, created_at, updated_at, execution_time_ms)     values (     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?     )
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ce_activity_uuid"
  Detail: Key (uuid)=(AWpKhMdKhBAmaVnZ4vza) already exists.
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:154) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.insert(DefaultSqlSession.java:141) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:51) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.insert(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.db.ce.CeActivityDao.insert(CeActivityDao.java:51) ~[sonar-db-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.queue.CeQueueImpl.remove(CeQueueImpl.java:181) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.queue.CeQueueImpl.cancelImpl(CeQueueImpl.java:156) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.InternalCeQueueImpl.cancel(InternalCeQueueImpl.java:128) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.CeQueueCleaner.verifyConsistency(CeQueueCleaner.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.CeQueueCleaner.clean(CeQueueCleaner.java:59) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.CeQueueInitializer.initCe(CeQueueInitializer.java:59) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.CeQueueInitializer.onServerStart(CeQueueInitializer.java:51) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.ServerLifecycleNotifier.notifyStart(ServerLifecycleNotifier.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.container.ComputeEngineContainerImpl.startupTasks(ComputeEngineContainerImpl.java:631) ~[sonar-ce-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.container.ComputeEngineContainerImpl.start(ComputeEngineContainerImpl.java:619) ~[sonar-ce-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.ComputeEngineImpl.startup(ComputeEngineImpl.java:43) ~[sonar-ce-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.startup(CeServer.java:175) [sonar-ce-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.attemptStartup(CeServer.java:165) [sonar-ce-5.6.6.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer$CeMainThread.run(CeServer.java:153) [sonar-ce-5.6.6.jar:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ce_activity_uuid"
  Detail: Key (uuid)=(AWpKhMdKhBAmaVnZ4vza) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:412) ~[postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.update(PreparedStatementHandler.java:44) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.update(RoutingStatementHandler.java:69) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doUpdate(ReuseExecutor.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.update(BaseExecutor.java:105) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.update(CachingExecutor.java:71) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.update(DefaultSqlSession.java:152) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
2019.07.03 11:25:17 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
2019.07.03 11:25:17 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is stopping
2019.07.03 11:25:17 INFO  web[o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2019.07.03 11:25:17 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2019.07.03 11:25:18 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service stopped
2019.07.03 11:25:18 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2019.07.03 11:25:19 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2019.07.03 11:25:19 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2019.07.03 11:25:20 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is stopped
2019.07.03 11:25:20 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2019.07.03 11:25:20 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping process
2019.07.03 11:25:20 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] stopping ...
2019.07.03 11:25:20 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] stopped
2019.07.03 11:25:20 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] closing ...
2019.07.03 11:25:20 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1562133268619] closed
2019.07.03 11:25:21 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

From the above log ERROR is
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ce_activity_uuid".

Any leads for the error..??

Comment: Did you add or change some plugins or is the the first setup? Try to start SonarQube after cleaning the temp directory manually and raise the log level if needed. Have a look at all log files.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen..

I tried clearing the temp and started it again, but no luck.

Am attaching the log here, can you please check once and suggest me.

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "ce_activity_uuid"
  Detail: Key (uuid)=(AWpKhMdKhBAmaVnZ4vza) already exists.

Comment: It seems that the PSQL plugin is causing the issue. I hope you have a backup; because this is the advised solution. But this is a paid plugin; maybe you can post a bug/support question.

Comment: [Support](https://www.sonarsource.com/support) Other "solutions" is starting with an empty database or solve the issue yourself by editing the database by hand (high risk).